# Is there a way to read a line from a file and get pause for few seconds, during pause a function checks whether user enters the same word or not?

Tags: qt

I am working to develop typing tutor project. i am unable to read a specific line from file and allow user to enter the word. so how can i fix this??

```
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
 QFile file("D:/programs/QT/file_handle/file.txt");
 if(!file.open(QFile::ReadOnly | QFile::Text))
     QMessageBox::warning(this,"title","file not open");

  QTextStream  in(&file);
  while(!in.atEnd()){
     line=in.readLine();
     ui->textBrowser->setPlainText(line);


  }


   file.close();
}

void MainWindow::on_pushButton_2_clicked()
{
QString str=ui->textEdit->toPlainText();

 if(line==str)
    ui->label->setText("they are same");
 else
    ui->label->setText("they are not same");
}
```

i expect to pause and pass control to  textEdit where user enters a word after reading the first line. but the actual output appears reading the final line of the file

Comment: Why don't you read the whole content of the file into memory (list) and work rather with the list elements than reading and pausing a file?

Comment: @vahancho actually i am new to qt...can you elaborate your statement with few codes...I suppose i could get you better in code..Well thanks for your advice

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this asynchronously.

Whether you read the whole file into a buffer / list or you keep the file open doesn't matter.

- You would need to make `file` (or buffer / list) a member of `MainWindow`.
- In `on_pushButton_clicked()` you would only read the first / next line and display it.